# Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, ssh

I use the functions below to copy files from one server to another. It works most of the time, but sometimes I start getting this error in log files:

```
Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

And it stops copying. Later for some reason, the error will stop and copying will start working again. What is the issue here?

```
function getConn($server,$username,$password)
{
    $connection = 0;

    if (function_exists("ssh2_connect")) 
    {
        $connection = ssh2_connect($server, 3817);
        if($connection)
        {
            if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password))
            {
                return $connection;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
function scp($server,$username,$password,$remotepath,$localpath)
{
    $connection = 0;
    $connection = $this->getConn($server,$username,$password);
    if($connection)
    {
        $ret = ssh2_scp_send($connection, $localpath, $remotepath, 0644);
        ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message `Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0` means that there's something off in your PHP configuration. Check to see if there's a line that says `extension=ssh2.so` in your php.ini. If so, remove it and check if everything is still working. Possibly, the extension=ssh2.so is loaded twice, meaning PHP will complain that the module is already loaded.

Good luck.

Comment: We had a case where there two files in the `/etc/php.d` directory that included the `ssh2` module. No idea how that happened, but we removed one of them and all seems well.

Comment: In FreeBSD, you will have /usr/local/etc/php.ini where these things would normally be set, but in addition, the package manager adds module specific ini files under /usr/local/etc/php - e.g. ext-20-ssh2.ini which contains the "extension=ssh2.so" reference. In these cases, remove the references from php.ini or the specific ini file under /usr/local/etc/php (prefer the former)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I commented out the one line in `ssh2.ini` located here: /etc/php5/mods-available/ssh2.ini

The content of this file now is as follow:

```
;extension=ssh2.so
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work, take a look inside /etc/php5/conf.d

If you see duplicate ssh2.ini files, remove any extra ones.

In my case I had 50-ssh2.ini and ss2.ini. Both files were providing the line:

```
extension=ssh2.so
```

For me removing 50-ssh2.ini solved the issue.