# svn update and commit stopped working

Tags: apache, svn

I've had subversion up and running with apache2 on an Ubuntu server for about a year now. I've used it almost every day without any problems until 4 days ago. I can browse my repositories through a web browser and I can also list my repositories using

`svn list http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn/repository`

But when I try to update or commit something the server hangs and I have to wait for about one minute until I can reach it again. I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find any solution. The apache error.log says

```
[Sun Mar 17 16:36:36 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Mar 17 16:36:37 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.17 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

and the other_vhosts_access.log says

```
- [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 401 677 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
- [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 401 677 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 200 876 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 200 876 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 453 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 453 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/bln/20 HTTP/1.1" 207 468 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/bln/20 HTTP/1.1" 207 468 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository HTTP/1.1" 207 554 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:45 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 453 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:45 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 453 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:45 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/bln/20 HTTP/1.1" 207 468 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
user [17/Mar/2013:16:37:45 +0100] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/!svn/bln/20 HTTP/1.1" 207 468 "-" "SVN/1.6.18 (r1303927) neon/0.29.0"
```

I've tried to reinstall subversion, restart the computer, verify and recover my repositories but nothing helped. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

**Update:** After looking into [Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726070/module-ssh2-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0), the error log says the following:

```
[Wed Mar 20 22:27:45 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Wed Mar 20 22:27:46 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.7.8 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726070/module-ssh2-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0 might help

Comment: I fixed it but it didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Okay... so what does the apache error.log say now that you've fixed it?

Comment: @Ben Barden The error.log now says like before but without the PHP warning:
[Wed Mar 20 22:27:45 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 20 22:27:46 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.7.8 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Okay, is there anything that you can think of that changed or happened shortly before the trouble started?  Did you apply any updates to Ubuntu/Apache/SVN or anything even remotely related?  Is it possible that you've run out of space in whatever memory you have set aside for SVN?

Comment: @BenBarden I'm not aware of any updates, can I see a log somewhere if I have applied any updates than can be the root to the problem? How can I check if I've run out of memory for SVN? Can't SVN use the entire disk space available on the disk cause there are plenty of space on my disk?

Comment: At this point I'm not so much telling you what the problem is as suggesting things to check.  Check how much RAM you've allocated to SVN, then watch the process list locally to see how much it tries to consume when you attempt to check something in over Apache.  It doesn't appear that svn has a default max repository size, so that's likely not an issue if you have plenty of space left on the partition that contains the repository (or the drive, if unpartitioned).  I have no idea where you'd be logging things.  What does the apache log say prior to the SIGTERM line?

Comment: Well, I can't see how much RAM it tries to allocate because when I do the SIGTERM also makes ssh stop. But what I can see is that I have about 500mb RAM free before i update/commit and that would be enough?  The error log says nothing prior to the SIGTERM line unfortunately.

Comment: What did you change in the server before the problems started? Any software update?

Comment: I would also blame a software update, or maybe a change in filesystem permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you're looking for but here goes:

*Switch to [Git](http://git-scm.com).*

You won't regret it! :-)

Comment: Yes, after putting in way too many hours to this I made the decision a couple of hours ago to convert to GIT.  And hopefully I won't regret it :-)

Comment: So my answer was the correct one after all!! You'll love Git! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once that was caused by a bug in a pre-commit hook.

Create a new test repository (without any hooks) and see if you can commit there.

You should also check the integrity of your repositories. `svnadmin verify` will not catch all errors - try `svnadmin dump REPOS > /dev/nul`.

Comment: I created a new repository but the same bug still occurs and the dump of my repositories seems to work fine.