# PHP Warning: Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh2-exec

This machine was working perfectly but for some reason now I can no longer execute bash scripts remotely on this server.

I can connect via ssh2_exec without issue, but when I try to run a bash script nothing happens.

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

$connection = ssh2_connect('serverip.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/root/incoming/test.sh &> /dev/null &");
```

In this instance test.sh is simply invoking wget to download a predefined file.

```
wget -O /root/incoming/files/myfile.zip http://remoteserver.com/file.zip
```

When I grep ssh2 locally on this machine :

```
php -m |grep ssh2
```

I get the expected result :

```
ssh2
```

But when I grep ssh2 remotely I get this :

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
ssh2
```

I found the following related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726070/module-ssh2-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0) stating that this error is possibly being thrown up by the extension being loaded twice in the config files.

So, as suggested I checked `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` - `extension=ssh2.so` isn't in there so this isn't the problem.

Next I followed the other suggestion and commented out `/etc/php5/mods-available/ssh2.ini` :

```
;extension=ssh2.so
```

But now when I try to grep ssh2 the module isn't loaded at all.
Is there anywhere else I can look for ssh2 being potentially double loaded?

Cheers!

EDIT - I did find a file called `20-ssh2.ini` in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` which was loading the extension again and have since deleted it, restarted apache but still getting the error.

EDIT II - Just realised that the file above is being recreated when I restart Apache, could this be the problem?

Comment: Is mods-available being included as well as mods-enabled? Look in the apache2.conf file

Comment: Just checked and no, I can't see it in there.